# Factoring a quadratic polynomial in the denominator, when finding the domain of f(x),

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

For real-valued functions, if the denominator is something like

$$ \sqrt{d^2 - x^2}, $$

Then the domain would be values for which

$$(d^2-x^2) > 0$$

or

$$ |x| < \sqrt{d},$$

but when factoring first to get

$$(d-x) * (d+x) > 0$$

and then proceeding by cases, i.e., case 1 would be finding x-values for which both factors are positive, and then finding x-values for which both factors are negative, seems to not work.

What is the flaw, when factoring the quadratic polynomial first?

Thanks,

Comment: $d-x^2$ is *not* $d^2-x^2$, that's all.

Comment: If it's $d^2$, the condition is $|x|<|d|$, and there's no flaw.

Comment: `then proceeding by cases, i.e. case 1 would be finding x-values for which both factors are positive` Assuming $d \gt 0\,$: $$\;\;\begin{cases}d - x \gt 0 \\ d+x \gt 0\end{cases} \iff \begin{cases}d \gt x \\ x \gt-d\end{cases} \iff -d \lt x \lt d \iff |x| \lt d\,$$.

The other case works out in similar fashion.

Comment: $d^2-x^2> 0\iff -d<x<d$ (supposing $d>0$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $d<0$ then $$d^2 \geq x^2 \Rightarrow |x |\leq |d| \Rightarrow -|d| \leq x \leq |d|$$

If $d>0$

We must have that $$d^2-x^2 \geq 0 \Rightarrow d^2 \geq x^2 \Rightarrow -d \leq x \leq d$$